# Link volume to collection

Tags: python, volumetrics

Helly everyone,

How can I correctly link a volume object to a collection?
When I'm creating a volume like this:

```
vol = bpy.data.volumes.new('Thing')
```

I wanted to link it like this:

```
bpy.context.scene.collection.children['Collection'].objects.link(vol)
```

That gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: CollectionObjects.link(): error with argument 1, "object" -  Function.object expected a Object type, not Volume
```

So it suggests, that I should link a volume, not an object. But how can I do that? There is no "volume" next to the object function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to understand a fundamental design orientation in Blender :

Objects are containers. They have a number of properties, and all objects are linked to some kind of `data`. Even Empty objects have a `data` attribute, which evaluates to `None`. Mesh, camera, lamp, lattice, curve objects and so on are all fundamentally the same type of containers. What separates them is the `data` they are linked to.

Here's how to create an Object, link your volume data to it, and link it to your collection:

```
import bpy
vol_data = bpy.data.volumes.new('Thing')
vol_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="MyVolumeObject", object_data=vol_data)
scene_col = bpy.context.scene.collection
# Notice what's linked here is the object, not the volume data :
scene_col.children.get("Collection", scene_col).objects.link(vol_obj)
```